# Difference between a pointer pointing to a static variable, and a static pointer pointing to some variable

Tags: c++, c

Is there any difference between

```
static int * pn;
```

and

```
int static * pn;
```

Basically I am looking for difference between a pointer pointing to a static variable, and a static pointer pointing to some variable, and not sure whether the above 2 declarations corresponds to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference. Here, the declaration specifier sequence is `static int` or `int static` and the order of specifiers in a declaration specifier sequence doesn't matter. Both of your declarations have type "pointer to int".

You can do other weird stuff like `int static unsigned const* pn;` if you hate people enough. I wrote [a question/answer that covers this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13808932/150634).

Comment: Thanks! Now I think both of them represent "pointer pointing to a static int", but is there a way to declare a "static pointer pointing to some int"?

Comment: @HailiangZhang No, they are both "static pointers to int"s. There's really no such thing as a "pointer to a static int". You just have a `int*` and it can point at any kind of `int`, static or not.

Comment: @HailiangZhang This is not a qualifier. `static` always applies only to the object that is declared, so here it is pointer.

Comment: @sftrabbit Thanks! So the "static pointer to ints" will survive both the "pointer" and its contents ("ints") after exiting the local scope, even though the contents was not dynamically allocated?

Comment: @HailiangZhang The pointer's content is the address it contains. Whatever it points to has nothing to do with the pointer. It can be static, it can not be static. If you don't tell it to point anywhere, it doesn't. It doesn't automatically point at some `int`. To make it point at an `int`, you'll have to do `pn = &some_int`.

Answer (score 7):

In C there is no difference but the second form is discouraged.

> (C99, 6.11.5p1) "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature"

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't know that. I'd +1 but I'm out of votes for the next 2 hours.