# const classname &obj == classname const &obj?

Tags: c++, c++11

Are these two constructors equivalent?

```
classname (const classname &obj) {
// body of constructor
}
```

vs.

```
classname (classname const &obj) {
// body of constructor
}
```

Comment: This question was answered before here.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808932/what-are-declarations-and-declarators-and-how-are-their-types-interpreted-by-the) is a very standardese answer but it might help some1 someday :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`const` protects its left side, unless there is nothing to its left, then and only then it protects its right side.

Applying this to your declarations, you should be able to know the answer.

Comment: Apart from this wart, parsing C/C++ types can be done using the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: @downvoted, please care to comment so me, OP and other readers will learn from my mistake.

Comment: So effectively a cosmetic 'issue' - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The declaration are equal.

As to the contents ... that is another matter

Comment: The contents are equal also - they both say `// body of constructor`!