# What is the difference between char *s[] and char (*s)[]?

Tags: c, pointers

When I read books about C language, the two level pointer bothered me a lot.

```
char s[5][5];
char *s[5];
char (*s)[5];
```

so what is the difference between them?

Comment: http://cdecl.org/, or install the `cdecl` program.

Comment: The second example is more clearly written as `char* s[5];`.

Answer (score 17):

In C, it is better to speak out the declaration. Then, it becomes intuitive. For this, you follow the right-left convention. Here is how it goes:

```
char *s[5];
```

How do you *speak* it? For that you start at the right of the variable name `s` and then go to the left.  So you start by saying "s is a/an", On the right, you see a `[]` and you say "s is an array ... ". And then you go to the left and see the `*`, and say "s is an array of pointers." And that is what it is. It si an array of 5 pointers. You can store different pointers in this array.

Now for the other one:

```
char (*s)[5];
```

You start the same way. "s is a/an", and then look at the `()`. Anything within the `()` is bound to `s` closer than anything outside. So the `*` is more closely bound with `s` than `[]`. So You now say, "s is a pointer ..." and now you go out of the parenthesis and see the `[]`. So you continue, "s is a pointer to an array". And that is exactly what it is. It is a pointer, which will point to the first element of an array.

Now follow the same logic and try to guess what the following will be:

```
int (*callme)(int a, int b)
int (*callme[10])(int a, int b)
```

Hint, the last one can be used to create lookup tables for functions.

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, there is also a `char` in the beginning. I have never ben able to figure out an easy way of speaking this, but is generally clear from the context. For example, in the first example, the `char` defines the type of the array, while in the second example, it defines  pointer. In the exercises I have posted, the `int` defines the type for the return values of the functions. Generally with definitions such as these, there will be exactly one item with the undefined type. And thats how I figure out where the type goes.

Comment: You forgot to include `char`; `char *s[5]` is not an array of 5 “different pointers” of any type, it is specifically an array of 5 pointers *to `char`*.

Comment: That is true. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I don't think it's fully correct to say `()` has greater precedence. Maybe you meant the presence of parentheses may alter the *binding* of complicated declarators.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that neither `a` or `b` are necessary to the declarations. `(int, int)` is sufficient.

Comment: Binding is definitely better here. My english isnt the best. Thanks!

Comment: I take it back. [How are (complex) declarations parsed in terms of precedence and associativity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685173/how-are-complex-declarations-parsed-in-terms-of-precedence-and-associativity) suggests that precedence does apply here.

Comment: Precedence and associativity is definitely how we look at the rules but the result is still the way in which the binding takes place. I do actually like the word very much.

Comment: can you tell me more about the lookup tables for functions?
`int (*callme[10])(int a, int b)`
how to use this ?

Comment: You can look up what the `interrupt vector table` is. You can simulate that for your error processing needs. You can also use that if you are programming a state machine (a robot, the turtle in Turtle Graphics, a simulation of a simple processor) which has a list of simple primitive commands, which you can store in an array, and then use an array of numbers for making a complex commands.

Comment: In a lot of GUI work (in the older days) different GUI events would provide different numbers, and you would have to match numbers to functions. This is also a place where you would be able to use this function.

Comment: So in summary, any place where you would use a lot of if conditions for selecting from a largish function list, you can use an array of pointers to functions. It is a little difficult to give examples in comments, but I am sure you can look up examples for `arrays of pointers to functions` in google.

Answer (score 8):

- first is 2 dimensional array of char
- second is array of pointer to char
- third is pointer to an array of char

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that a 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays.

Comment: Or an `array of 5, 5 character arrays`

Answer (score 3):

While [declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030845/4256882) was covered, perhaps differences in *usage* should also be pointed out:

`char s[5][5];` --

- `s` points to an area of allocated memory (heap if global, stack if local),
- you may safely write up to 25 char values at `s[0][0]` .. `s[4][4]` (or at `s[0]` .. `s[24]`),
- `sizeof(s)` == 25.

`char *s[5];` --

- `s` points to an area of allocated memory (heap if global, stack if local),
- you may safely write up to 5 pointer values at `s[0]` .. `s[4]`,
- `sizeof(s)` == 40 (*).

`char (*s)[5];` --

- `s` does **not** point to any allocated memory -- it's merely an uninitialized pointer at this point,
- you may safely write one pointer value at `&s`,
- `sizeof(s)` == 8 (*).

(*) note: assuming a 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 3):

1.char s[5][5];
  Here s is two dimensional array with 5 rows and 5 columns. Where in this 5 rows and 5 columns you will save element of type character.

2.char *s[5];
  s is a one dimensional array with 5 elements each element is of type pointer to character.

3.char (*s)[5];
  s is a pointer here not array. S points to a array of characters. for eg.

`char arr[5][5];
   char(*s)[5];
   s = arr;`

s[0][0] will be same as array of arr[0][0]

Comment: Is `char(*s)[5]`just a pointer? are there some difference between
`char *s`,`char (*s)[5]` and  `char (*s)[10]`?

Comment: @storen  Yes char(*s)[5] is just a pointer. But it is a pointer to  an array of char. For Eg: 1. `char(*s)[5]; char arr[2][5]; s = arr;` In this s is pointing to an array of 5 elements which is first row of arr. If you do s++ then s points to second row of arr. 2. 'char *s; char arr[5]; s = arr; Here s points to first element of the array which is character. If you do s++ it points to next character`

Comment: but I want to know how the compiler know this pointer's type is int,the other is char? when we define a `int * a` type，does the compiler not only store the value `a`，but also store the type of the `a`, so it may has some extra memory expense?