# static and volatile qualifiers after type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, qualifiers

Bjarne explains why const can go either before or after a type.

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constplacement

> ```
> "const T" and "T const" were - and are - (both) allowed and equivalent.
> [...]
> ```
>
> Why? When I invented "const" (initially named "readonly" and had a
>   corresponding "writeonly"), I allowed it to go before or after the
>   type because I could do so without ambiguity.

My immediate thought was, "Ok, that makes sense, but if that's the reason then why is const special?" Apparently it isn't. Both clang and gcc emit no warnings for the following.

```
int volatile myint;
int static myotherint;
```

It makes sense that this would be valid but I've never seen this syntax used or even mentioned as a possibility. Is placing static and volatile qualifiers after a type valid C++?

*How would one determine this from the text of the Standard?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These pieces are actually rather widely separated in the standard. `static` is a storage class, as specified in §7.1.1/1:

```
storage-class-specifier:
    register
    static
    thread_local
    extern
    mutable
```

That's used in a *decl-specifier*, as defined in §1.7:

```
decl-specifier:
    storage-class-specifier
    type-specifier
    function-specifier
    friend
    typedef
    constexpr

decl-specifier-seq:
    decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seqopt
    decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq
```

So, this allows either `static int` or `int static` to specify a type. Likewise, you could declare a friend function as either `friend int f();` or `int friend f();`.

`const` or `volatile` can only get involved when you actually declare something, so it falls under "declarators" in § 8. This part of the grammar is long enough I'm too lazy to format it all, but it specifies *init-declarator-list* at the top level, then *declarator*, and (skipping a few levels) gets down to `cv-qualifier` which is either `const` or `volatile`. At least by my reading, it basically allows the `const` or `volatile` to be freely intermixed with the other things that specify a type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that syntax is fine. The first part of the declaration grammar is a sequence of *decl-specifiers*. These include storage class specifies, type specifiers, function specifies, `friend`, `typedef`, and `constexpr`. The grammar allows them to appear in any order. However, the semantic rules placed on them introduce some restrictions. For example, in a variable declaration there must always be one type specifier that is not a cv-qualifier (`const` or `volatile`). There also must never be more than one storage class specifier (except `thread_local` can appear with `static` or `extern`).

Note that the sequence of decl-specifiers comes before any compound type syntax, such as pointers, references, arrays, and so on. For example, the sequence of decl-specifiers is marked in the following examples:

```
static const int *p;
|              |

char volatile static *(&p)[20];
|                  |
```

Note that `volatile` is a cv-qualifier like `const`, so the reasons for allowing `volatile` in the example you gave are the same as for `const`. These keywords can also appear deeper within the declaration (as in `int *volatile x;`).

By convention, we write storage class specifies first, followed by type specifies and cv-qualifiers where appropriate. I prefer to write my cv-qualifications *after* the type specifiers to which they correspond, as it is more consistent.

You may want to have a read of [What are declarations and declarators and how are their types interpreted by the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13808932/150634).

Answer (score 0):

well, following is what i guess. i try to interpret this.

```
static int *ptr1;
int* static ptr2;
```

first one means it's a pointer, pointing to a static integer.
second one means that that it's a static variable, with type of integer pointer.

i think the other way should has the similar intepretation.

Comment: `int* static ptr2;` is not a valid declaration.

Comment: @JosephMansfield you tested it? would int static *ptr3; work?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrrr That one is fine.

Comment: @JosephMansfield yeah, it looks like a static pointer pointing to an integer.