# C11: how does fixed-length array declaration fit in the C11 standard's specification?

Tags: c, c11

The C11 standard (N1548) section 6.7.6 set forth the specifications of a declarator.

In my understanding (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808933/8385554) about dissecting a C declaration), an array declaration `int * arr[5];` has two parts: (a) declaration specifiers `int`, and (b) declarator `* arr[5]`. My problem is how to interpret the declarator part according to the C11 standard.

The standard says:
[image]
Ok, so `*` clearly corresponds to the "pointer" part. Therefore, `arr[5]` must correspond to the "direct-declarator" part. However, in the expansion of "direct-declarator" in this standard, it seems there is not an entry that matches `arr[5]` -- because it seems the constant expression `5` in the bracket does not match with "type-qualifier-list" or "assignment-expression".

So how does this declaration fit in the C11 standard's specification?

Comment: The answer you're referencing refers to C++11, not C11. That may or may not lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5` is *assignment-expression*.

If you look at the definition of *assignment-expression*, one of it is *conditional-expression*. And one definition for that is *logical-OR-expression*. By tracking down this definition chain, you'll eventually reach *primary-expression*, for which on one definition is *constant*.

Comment: I think the key to understanding this is that all operators in C are linked together in one long chain, to specify their precedence. The assignment operators is the group with lowest precedence of all (except the comma operator).