# Where in the Standard does it indicate that pointers, references, pointers to members, arrays and functions are simple-declarations?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13808932/1042389) in SO, @Josehp Mansfield basically says that, in the first paragraph of his answer. But I'd like to know how does one deduce this from the standard itself?

Comment: There's a citation in the answer: C++11 §7/1. is the question how to interpret the citation, how to find the document, or something else?

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#1

Comment: @chris Now, I can see what you mean. Pointers, references, . . . , and functions are the only entities in C++ that can be represented by a [_simple-declaration_](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration). Great answer. Thank you.