# Using auto and decltype to return reference from member function in a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, decltype

How can I coerce a function in a templated class to return a reference to a member variable using auto/decltype?

Here's a trivialized example of what I'm trying to do. Suppose you've got a templated class that stores something in a private member variable, `a_` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
  T a_;

public:
  A(T a) : a_(a) {}

  // 1. Return const reference to a_
  const T & get() const { return a_; }

  // 2. Return non-const reference to a_
  T & get() { return a_; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A<int> a(3);

  const auto & a1 = a.get(); // 1. Return const reference to a_
  //a1 = 4;  // Shouldn't compile
  std::cout << "Value of a = " << a.get() << std::endl;

  auto & a2 = a.get(); // 2. Return non-const reference to a_
  a2 = 5;
  std::cout << "Value of a = " << a.get() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The expected/desired output is:

```
Value of a = 3
Value of a = 5
```

But now, suppose I want the compiler to deduce the type returned by the const and non-const `get()` functions in `A<T>` and I want to ensure both calls return **references** to `a_`.

My best guess is currently:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
  T a_;

public:
  A(T a) : a_(a) {}

  // 1. Return const reference to a_
  const auto get() const -> std::add_lvalue_reference<const decltype(a_)>::type
  {
    return a_;
  }

  // 2. Return non-const reference to a_
  auto get() -> std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(a_)>::type
  {
    return a_;
  }
};
```

but that fails to compile. The first error given by GCC is:

```
decltype.cpp:11:29: error: expected type-specifier
decltype.cpp:11:26: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
decltype.cpp:11:29: error: ‘add_lvalue_reference’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
```

The motivation for this lies outwith my distilled example code, but stems from an attempt to reduce the number of parameters a template takes when one (or more) of those parameters is used solely to specify a return type which the compiler should (I think) be able to deduce by itself. Note: in the real world, the return type of `get()` is not that of `a_`, but is the return type of some function `f(a_)` which I know to be deducible by the compiler. Thus my need for auto/decltype in this example.

The thing that's puzzling me is that the compiler can deduce the return type correctly using near-identical code in a non-templated class:

```
class A
{
private:
  int a_;

public:
  A(int a) : a_(a) {}

  // 1. Return const reference to a_
  const auto get() const -> std::add_lvalue_reference<const decltype(a_)>::type
  {
    return a_;
  }

  // 2. Return non-const reference to a_
  auto get() -> std::add_lvalue_reference<decltype(a_)>::type
  {
    return a_;
  }
};
```

Any help to understand what I'm missing will be greatly appreciated.

Details:

```
Centos 6.5
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)
```

Comment: `const auto get() const` For a trailing-return-type, you may only use `auto` before the function's name, not `const auto`.

Comment: @dyp Are you sure? It works if I add `typename` where needed.

Comment: @jrok That's what clang says. I can look up the grammar..

Comment: @jrok Looks like dyp is correct - [dcl.spec.auto] The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` type-specifiers designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later, either by deduction from an initializer or by explicit specification with a trailing-return-type. Both gcc and VS2013 accept `const auto` without any complaints though.

Comment: @Praetorian I think that paragraph does not directly forbid using `const auto`, since it also applies to variable declarations (`auto` is replaced). However, look at [dcl.fct]/2 which forbids it explicitly

Comment: @jrok 8.3.5[dcl.fct]/p2 says "In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form [grammar for function declaration with trailing return type], `T` shall be the single type-specifier `auto`."

Comment: @T.C. Exactly. Time for some bug reports.

Comment: @T.C. and dyp: Yes, I'm reading the same thing. But what is *derived-declarator-type-list*? :)

Comment: @jrok Uhhh IIRC this is defined every time it is mentioned (i.e., it's a meaningless transparent alias)

Comment: @jrok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779273/in-the-standard-what-is-derived-declarator-type

Comment: @dyp I'd have expected [dcl.spec.auto] to say optionally cv-qualified if it was allowed, but then again, the section pointed out by TC doesn't say anything about `decltype(auto)` so it could be an error.

Comment: @Praetorian Well [dcl.spec.auto] does implicitly allow cv-qualifications; [dcl.fct]/2 requires the use of a *trailing-return-type*, which cannot be combined with `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: BTW `// 1. Return const reference to a_` is false, it returns a reference to `a_` which is bound into a *const reference*.

Comment: As a clarification to any visitors, `const auto` isn't needed in that context anyway; unlike with variable declarations using `auto`, function-auto _does_ maintain cv-qualification.

Comment: Just curious, why do you have a non-const `get` instead of an assignment operator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to mention it, you don't actually have to use `std::add_lvalue_reference` to get the behaviour you want. This works just as well and is more readable in my book.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A {
private:
    T a_;

public:
    A(T a) : a_(a) {}

    auto get() const -> const decltype(a_) & {
        return a_;
    }

    auto get() -> decltype(a_) & {
        return a_;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a(1);
    std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;
    a.get() = 2;
    std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;
}
```

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrap `a_` in an extra pair of parentheses in the trailing return type to get the type of the expression `a_` instead of the declared type of the variable `a_` ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/350cbca560f39939)):

```
// 1. Return const reference to a_
auto get() const -> decltype((a_))
{
  return a_;
}

// 2. Return non-const reference to a_
auto get() -> decltype((a_))
{
  return a_;
}
```

or if [C++14 or above](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6033a7e4a5ce2815) is available:

```
// 1. Return const reference to a_
auto& get() const
{
  return a_;
}

// 2. Return non-const reference to a_
auto& get()
{
  return a_;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `auto& get() const { return a_; }` be `const auto& get() const { return a_; }` if you want to return a const reference? The const a after the function name means that you can call the member function on a constant object it belongs to.

Comment: `auto&`  can deduce a reference to const type just fine. `const auto&` in this case would not be more correct, only more explicit.