# Understanding derived-declarator-type-list and array decalrator

Tags: c++, arrays

The section 8.3.4/1 N3797:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
>
> and the type of the identifier in the
>   declaration T D1 is `“derived-declarator-type-list T”`, then the type
>   of the identifier of D is an array type;

I've understood what is the `derived-declarator-type-list` from that [**Q|A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779273/in-the-standard-what-is-derived-declarator-type).

But I'm interested in an example of the declaration `T D` such that the type of the identifier in the decalaration `T D1` hasn't form of `“derived-declarator-type-list T”`.

That is the type of identifier of T D where D has the form

```
D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

isn't an array type. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we are in section 8 about declarators.  In this context `[]` cannot designate subscripting operator (expression, chapter 5.2.1) nor the lambda introducer (expression, chapter 5.1.2) but only arrays.

Next, we have to consider that we have simple and more complex declarators:

```
int ndigit[10];    // T is int, D is ndigit[10] which is an array type 
                   // the type of the identifier ndigit is derived declarator type int 
char *str[512];    // T is char*,  D is str[10] wich is an array type
                   // the type of the identifier str is derived declarator type char*
```

Knowing all this, we have to breathe in profundly and step back a little bit from our linguisic habits.

As programmer, when we read an english sentence like

```
    If P1 and P2 then P3
```

we instinctively understand that there are two conditions and translate in c++ :

```
    if (P1 && P2) P3;    // 2 conditions must be true and P3 will be done
```

But english is not C++ ! There are also other valid meanings.  Take this unrelated mathematical example :

```
    ax²+bx+c =0   
    if Δ =b²-4ac and Δ >0 then there are two distinct roots
```

In this example, it is obvious, that `Δ =b²-4ac` is not an additional condition for having two roots.  It's just a way to introduce (without making an extra sentence) a naming convention that is used in the condition or the conclusion .

Of course one can argue that this style is not a good practice, and that we should have written:

```
    ax²+bx+c =0   
    let's define Δ =b²-4ac 
    If Δ >0 then there are two distinct roots
```

I completely agree !  Now let's apply this kind of reading to the standard:

```
    In a declaration T D where D has the form
        D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
    Let the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 be “derived-declarator-type-list T”
    Then the type of the identifier of D is an array type;
```

Would this be more understandable for you ?

This kind of sentences make it clear that the main goal of a standard is not to be easy to read, but to express unambiguously complex language constructs, and completely conver all their semantic and syntactic variants.