# Does T D[N] always declare an object of array type?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, declaration

I'm confused about [[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1):

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ *constant-expression<sub>opt</sub>* ] *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is “*derived-declarator-type-list* T”, then the type of the identifier of D is an array type; ...

Consider the declaration:

```
int (*p)[42];
```

This declaration satisfies the grammar described above (and does not satisfy the grammar described in previous paragraphs), so this paragraph should apply, thus we conclude that the type of `p` is an array type. However, we know that the type of `p` is `pointer to array of 42 int`, which is a pointer type.

Am I missing something? Or `pointer to array of 42 int` is indeed an array type?

Comment: `D1` is `(*p)`, so the type of `*p` is an array type, therefore the type of `p` is pointer to array type.

Comment: @Barmar that sounds like an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @Barmar The specification says "the type of the identifier of D is an array type", and I think "the identifier of D" refers to `p`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Maybe, but I'm not really sure, since the spec says "the identifier of D`, and the identifier is just `p`.

Comment: Maybe this is only talking about the case where `D1` is an identifier. All the examples in that section are like that. I'm not sure where it talks about your syntax.

Comment: @Barmar If it only cares about the case where D1 is an identifier, it would simply use T instead of "derived-declarator-type-list T".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779273/in-the-standard-what-is-derived-declarator-type

Comment: Yeah this wording doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think this qualifies as an [editorial issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/How-to-submit-an-editorial-issue)

Comment: @cpplearner I have proposed [an issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2175).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of the wording of the standard. Of course, `int (*p)[42];` is not an array type, but satisfies the grammar in [[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1) (and does not satisfy the previous grammars in [[dcl.meaning]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#5), [[dcl.meaning]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#6), [[dcl.ptr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ptr#1), [[dcl.ref]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1) or [[dcl.mptr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.mptr#1)), so [dcl.array]/1 should apply.

I have posted an [editorial issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2175).

Comment: Could you explain why [the replacement](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/f2a857ff8ef6653ea4b80aa460710923f3a20147) of _identifier_ by _declarator-id_ solved the issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
int (*p)[42];
```

You said

> This declaration satisfies the grammar described above.

When seen that way, `*p` is an array of 42 `int` elements, which is true. That fits the type of `p` just right. It is a pointer to "an array of 42 `int`s".

Comment: "then the type of the identifier of D is an array type". It says "identifier". There is also a [related and similar sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1.sentence-5), they seem to contradict to each other.

Comment: When seen that way, the grammar does not match. `(*p)` is not an identifier.

Comment: It does not require `D1` to be an identifier.

Comment: @xskxzr, Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779331/434551) will be helpful.