# Using the Standard, how does one explain the error messages below emitted by clang and GCC?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given the snippet

```
int f(int) [];
```

GCC and clang emit the following error messages:

[clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec0e130cd5aa1d83)

`error: function cannot return array type int []`

[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bbaa0cea6ba9b66)

`error: 'f' declared as function returning an array`

If we consider [[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1)

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form `D1 [` *constant-expression*<sub>*opt*</sub>`]`
>   *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> and the type of the identifier in the
>   declaration `T D1` is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, **then the type of
>   the identifier of `D` is an array type**; if the type of the identifier of
>   `D` contains the `auto` type-specifier, the program is ill-formed. `T` is
>   called the array element type; this type shall not be a reference
>   type, *cv* `void`, a function type or an abstract class type. `...`

the compilers should complain about an ill-formed declaration of an array of functions.

What am I missing?

Comment: The standard requires a diagnostic, but does not specify its form. You're getting a diagnostic, so what's the problem? (They're entitled to guess what you meant, since it doesn't actually mean anything.)

Comment: @AlanStokes Fair enough, but I still find the definition of declarators in the standard confusing.

Comment: I think "*the type of the identifier of `D` is an array type*" is a bug in the standard. Further down it says "if the constant expression is omitted, the type of the identifier of `D` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* array of unknown bound of `T`”", which is correct.

Comment: Seems like both compilers are trying to do _something_, since the error messages are so similar.  MSVC thinks the same thing, see http://rextester.com/RSKH14053.  Maybe there's more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: The specification is nonsensical, see https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2175

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50823601/1848654

Comment: @cpplearner Great link. This clearly answers my question.

Comment: @cpplearner What does zygoloid mean when he writes: " However, in a declaration in which we have a non-outermost array declarator chunk, such as: 
`int *p[42];`" in his comment in Github issue 2175? Isn't `[42]` an outermost chunk in the declaration `int *p[42];`?

Comment: Also `int []` is an incomplete type (cf 9.2.3.4/1 - if the constant expression is omitted, the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list array of unknown bound of T”, an incomplete object type). I don't see how you could return it by value.

Comment: @Alexander [The rules for parsing declaration are applied in order](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#3), so here the [pointer rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#dcl.ptr-1) is applied firstly instead of the array rule.