# Why can't I initialize an auto deduced pointer with nullptr?

Tags: c++, syntax, casting

I was trying to do something similar to this:

```
auto foo = int*(nullptr);
```

Which with VC++ doesn't compile with the error message:

> Type name is not allowed

And with GCC 8.2 doesn't compile with:

> Expected primary expression before 'int'

I was really curious as to why this appears to be an illegal syntax. In my mind it should be fine since literals can be initialized like this.

```
auto foo = int(2);
```

The only way I could think off to get this to work was to either make a type alias or do this:

```
auto foo = std::add_pointer_t<int>(nullptr);
```

I tried googling for this but frankly I don't even know how to properly formulate this question since my standardese is weak. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Most vexing parse or similar? Try `int*{}` instead.

Comment: why would you use `auto` when the only effect is that you need the cast? It does not answer the question, but if you write `int* foo = nullptr;` the "problem" does not exist

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried that with GCC 8.2, Clang 7.0 and the latest VC++, doesn't work either.

Comment: @user463035818 Why I would want to do this is irrelevant to my question. I'm wondering _why_ it's not possible. I'm not asking for good practices I'm asking why is this illegal in the language.

Comment: As I said, it does not answer the quesiton, but I disagree that it is irrelevant. You write "The only way I could think off .." but the only way I can think of to write this is without `auto`. Are you trying to get rid of the first A in almost always auto ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `auto`, the RHS in itself is invalid. `(int*) nullptr;` would work instead. https://wandbox.org/permlink/xRTCeGhjFAP80Z7O

Comment: @user463035818 Quoting myself 
The only way I could think off to get *this* to work was
Again, I'm asking about the syntax to get the first code piece in this question to compile. All this text is just an attempt to have a better formulated question than "Why doesn't this work"

Comment: It occurred to me that `static_cast` should work in this case. Maybe the problem here is that you used a C style cast.

Comment: `int* foo = nullptr;` is correct syntax that has the same effect, as your first line, not sure why you insist that it is not relevant. Of course, independent of that it is an interesting question to know why the line as you wrote it is wrong....

Comment: @user463035818 My question clearly asks about initializing a variable deduced by the compiler via auto.

Comment: but `auto` just deduces the exact type you write on the rhs. Afaik there is literally no difference between `auto foo = (int*)(nullptr);` and `int* foo = nullptr;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int*` is a ["derived declarator type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779273/in-the-standard-what-is-derived-declarator-type)(not a standard term, but useful for reasoning about this). A functional style cast notation (which is what `int(2)` is) can only contain a [*"A simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier"*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.type.conv#1). A derived declarator type doesn't fall under either category.

You have to either:

- write it out in the form of a C-style cast:

  ```
  auto foo = (int*) nullptr;
  ```
- or in the form of a C++-style cast:

  ```
  auto foo = static_cast<int*>(nullptr);
  ```
- or alias the pointer type:

  ```
  using iptr = int*;
  auto foo = iptr(nullptr);
  ```

Comment: This summed it up very well for me. Thank you. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 8):

`int*(nullptr)` doesn't work because only **single-word type name** could be used in [functional cast expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). Note that `int*` is not a single-word type name, while `int` is (and then `int(2)` works fine).

> The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a single expression in parentheses.

As the workaround, you can use `typedef`,

```
typedef int* int_pointer;
auto foo = int_pointer (nullptr);
```

or change it to c-style cast expression.

```
auto foo = (int*) nullptr;
```

Comment: Amazing answer as well, thank you. I really appreciate it.